# Use a button in Excel to copy information from one sheet to another on a new row

Tags: vba, excel

I have one workbook with two sheets. Sheet 1 is laid out to look like a form with a submit button and named **TravelRequest**. Sheet 2 is just a database that is collected from sheet 1 and named **TravelLog**.

Here is how it works now:

1. User on Sheet 1 fills out the proper sections of the Excel form
2. User clicks on the Submit button
3. Data gets copied onto Sheet 2 in its own columns all in 1 row and clears Sheet 1 entries
4. When the next user fills out the form it should add a new ROW in Sheet 2

So, right now my script copies one cell to another specified cell and I tried many different codes from this website but cant seem to get any to work, also my copy script is hardcoded copy & paste operations. I don't know how to work around that.

I can upload the Excel sheet somewhere if anyone needs it for helping out here.

```
Sub Submit()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("L5").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("B6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("C5").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("C6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("G5").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("D6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("c10").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("E6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("c9").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("F6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("I9").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("G6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("I10").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("H6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("C13").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("I6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("C14").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("J6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("C15").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("K6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("C16").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("L6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("C17").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("M6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("C18").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("N6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("i13").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("O6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("i14").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("P6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("i15").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("Q6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("i16").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("R6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("i17").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("S6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("h20").Copy
    Sheets("TravelLog").Range("W6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

*** EDIT ***

With druciferre's answer, I'm getting this error

> ERROR OVERFLOW

on this line

```
Worksheets("TravelLog").Range(Dest).Value = Worksheets("TravelRequest").Range(Field).Value
```

Here is the updated `refTable` array.

```
refTable = Array("B = L5", "C = C5", "D=G5", "E=C10", "F=C9", "G=I9", "H=I10", "I=C13", "J=C14", "K=C15", "L=C16", "M=C17", "N=C18", "O=I13", "P=I14", "Q=I15", "R=I16", "S=I17", "W=H20")
```

Comment: While it doesn't directly answer your question, there is specific functionality built in to Excel to do exactly what you want, without the need to write your own macro. See for example http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/ss/090717_data_form.htm

Comment: Yeah I know about that and it works great, its just that my company wants an actual form style design in excel and not just that window. Would of made my life easier if it was ok to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant
refTable = Array("B = L5", "C = C5", "D=G5", "E=C10", "F=C9")
Dim Row As Long
Row = Worksheets("TravelLog").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 
For Each trans In refTable
    Dim Dest As String, Field As String
    Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & Row
    Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range(Dest).value = Worksheets("TravelRequest").Range(Field).value
Next
```

In the `refTable` array, each item is a translation of the form field to the destination column. So, if `L5` from the form is supposed to go column `B` on the log, then you write `B = L5`. The code can handle with the spaces or without.

Comment: Your code would just create the exact same thing from one sheet to the other right? But if the user erases any information from the form then the sheet 2 will be updated to that too?

Comment: @user3438974, I changed the code so that it will insert a new row.

Comment: The script works good at creating a new row but it is copying data from travellog and not from travelrequest sheet. How can this be fixed? so the B/C/D/E/F are travel log and the L5/G5/C10 are from travel request.

Comment: It will copy from whatever sheet is in focus. If you want to insure it's copying from TravelRequest, then change `= Range(Field).value` to `= Worksheets("TravelRequest").Range(Field).Value`.

Comment: Wow it seems to be working! Your a genius! I have another question about clearing the form on the travelrequst sheet and updating its invoice number. Should I hopen a new topic or post here?

Comment: I added all the new cells and now when I run it i get an error on this line Worksheets("TravelLog").Range(Dest).Value = Worksheets("TravelRequest").Range(Field).Value says OVERFLOW ERROR

Comment: seems to be ok, error only happens sometimes. is there a reason why?

Comment: @user3438974, In regards to your question about cleaning the form, you can post it as a separate topic or update the question here. It's up to you. As for the error, can you post your updated version of the `refTable` array? Can you also tell me what kind of values (examples would be good) you're entering into the cells on the TravelRequest worksheet?

Comment: Alright I have updated the new reftable above. The values I enter are text mostly with some numbers.

Comment: @user3438974, Everything looks okay, so it has to be a value that you're entering. Next time it happens add a Watch for the `Dest` and `Field` variables. See what those values are when it breaks. Make sure they are valid cell references, and look and see what value is in the TravelLog sheet for the cell referenced in the `Field` variable. If you're not sure how to add a Watch, there is a [Youtube video on how to do it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19JTjCtFPeI). Post exact text in the cell that caused the error and I should be able to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Seems like I fixed it, I had 2 date value cells and it was formated to date, but when a person entered too many numbers in it the program went into overflow. I set it to general format since they might use words and numbers in it. Seems to work now.

Comment: I will be starting a invoicing question and also a checkbox question too, if you can help me out will post them now. thanks for this one its solved!